# react js get jwt token to load API but it return 401 after login

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spring-boot, jwt, fetch-api

I am trying to get my jwt token after login, to get my API, but when I make this code like its return 401 status code. This is my code:

```
componentDidMount() {

let user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
console.log(user.accessToken)
fetch("http://localhost:8080/api/dashboard/dummy", {

   mode: 'no-cors',
   method: 'GET',
   withCredentials: true,
   credentials: 'include',
   headers:{
              Authorization: 'Bearer ' + user.accessToken,
      },
      
    })
    
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(parsedJSON => parsedJSON.results.map(data => (
    {
      id: `${data.id.name}`,
      firstName: `${data.name.card1}`,
      lastName: `${data.name.card2}`,
      location: `${data.name.card3}`,
      thumbnail: `${data.dob.age}`,

    }
  )))
  .then(items => this.setState({
    items,
    isLoaded: false
  }))
  .catch(error => console.log('parsing failed', error))
}
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: 401 status code means you're unauthorized therefore even though you're hitting the endpoint correctly, something is off with your token. Have you tested the endpoint with Postman? Also, what does your console.log(user.accessToken) print?

Comment: i already tested with postman and its work correctly, Also when i print console user.accessToken its work

Comment: Double check your headers. For example, the method is set as GET but it's usually a POST request.

Comment: thankyou so much for you help, i just use get method to load that api data